# Translating: There are 3 items in your cart

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

While trying to translate my website to Dutch, I can't seem to translate the sentences

> There are 3 items in your cart.
>
> There is 1 item in your cart.

I have already edited the .csv files `Mage_Checkout` and `Mage_Catalog` and tried inline translation, but the text is still shown in English.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: what your language of your store..

Comment: clear cache..  and check then..

Comment: The store is Dutch, already cleared my cache and checked the language settings. It's just this sentence that won't translate. Even with 'There are %s items in your cart' it won't work.

Comment: where have you done the change?? tell the path

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? If you are on Linux, try `grep -nRP "There are.*items? in your cart" 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Off topic?? LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have correctly edited your `CSV` file and have translated via Inline Translation, the last step would be to disable the `Translations` in your `Cache Management`

Click `System->Cache`
Select `Translations`, under `Actions` select `Disable`
Click `Submit`

Refresh the page with the translations.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/locale/languagecode_COUNTRYCODE
```

and put your translated strings inside this translate.csv.

For your case it should be the dutch language code and then put this

```
"There are %s items in your cart","WHATEVER YOU WANT TO HAVE HERE"
```

Be careful it is all case-sensitive so make sure you´ve the first column exactly as it appears in the US version